# hover to show siblings element but flicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use mouseenter and mouseleave  to toggle a delete button using js below :

```
 $('body').on("mouseenter",".item", function(){
      $(this).next().show();
    }).on("mouseleave", ".item",function(){
      $(this).next().hide();
    });
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="item"></div>
<span class="dlt">x</span>
```

I did a demo http://jsfiddle.net/sm3dx99k/ to reproduce my problem. When I hover into the `x button` it will flick, I expect it to as I want it to be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this there is no flickering. I made a few changes to your js

```js
$('body').on("mouseenter",'.parent', function () {
     $(this).children('.dlt').show();
 }).on("mouseleave",'.parent', function () {
    $(this).children('.dlt').hide();
 });
```

```css
.item {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    background:orange;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.dlt {
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:-55px 30px;
    display:none;
}
.parent{
  display:inline-block;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div class="item"></div>
<span class="dlt">x</span>
  </div>
<div class="parent">
<div class="item"></div>
<span class="dlt">x</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: will this work on future element? that's why I used on(). Also u have to use $(this), what if I have multiple circle and x?

Comment: @DeanJason future element ?

Comment: can't I bind to body using on()?